# CMake generated project for VS2017 requires VS2010 to be installed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have CMake project generated for VS2017. When I try to build **Release** configuration from the command line using `cmake.exe --build "build\release_2017" --target pemd5` it fails with an error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(65,5): error MSB8020: The
 build tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v100 build tools, please install Visual Studio
 2010 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, a
nd then selecting "Retarget solution". [D:\dev\syscore\build\release_2017\comlib\comlib.vcxproj]
```

The same command works flawlessly for the **Debug** configuration. What's even stranger is that if I load the generated solution with VS2017 IDE it builds correctly.
I also tried to build the .sln file with MSBuild.exe using `msbuild.exe build\release_2017\SysCore.sln`. While the results are slightly better I still get similar errors:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 1/7/2021 10:07:46 AM.
Project "D:\dev\syscore\build\release_2017\SysCore.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
D:\dev\syscore\build\release_2017\SysCore.sln.metaproj : error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Release|x86" is invalid. Please spec
ify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platfo
rm="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration. [D:\dev\syscore\build\release_2017\SysCore.sln]
Done Building Project "D:\dev\syscore\build\release_2017\SysCore.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"D:\dev\syscore\build\release_2017\SysCore.sln" (default target) (1) ->
(ValidateSolutionConfiguration target) ->
  D:\dev\syscore\build\release_2017\SysCore.sln.metaproj : error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Release|x86" is invalid. Please sp
ecify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Plat
form="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration. [D:\dev\syscore\build\release_2017\SysCore.sln]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

Only if I also specify the platform as well the build succeeds (`msbuild.exe build\release_2017\SysCore.sln -p:Platform=Win32`).

None of my CMakeLists.txt scripts in the source directory has conditional CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES sections.
Both **Debug** and **Release** were generated by VS2017 using the command:

```
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe  -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="D:\dev\syscore\install\release_2017"  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES="Release" "D:\dev\syscore"
```

and

```
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe  -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="D:\dev\syscore\install\debug_2017"  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES="Debug" "D:\dev\syscore"
1> Working directory: D:\dev\syscore\build\debug_2017
```

My CMakeSettings.json looks like:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "debug_2017",
            "generator": "Visual Studio 15 2017",
            "configurationType": "Debug",
            "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x86" ],
            "buildRoot": "${workspaceRoot}\\build\\${name}",
            "installRoot": "${workspaceRoot}\\install\\${name}",
            "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
            "buildCommandArgs": "-v:n -m:8",
            "ctestCommandArgs": "",
            "variables": []
        },
      {
        "name": "release_2017",
        "generator": "Visual Studio 15 2017",
        "configurationType": "Release",
        "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x86" ],
        "buildRoot": "${workspaceRoot}\\build\\${name}",
        "installRoot": "${workspaceRoot}\\install\\${name}",
        "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
        "buildCommandArgs": "-v:d -m:8",
        "ctestCommandArgs": "",
        "variables": []
      },
....
```

Any suggestions???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug in CMake. The only way around it I found so far is to add explicit configuration and platform for MSBuild.exe on cmake.exe command line (e.g. `cmake.exe --build ..... -- -p:Configuration=Debug -p:Platform=Win32`)